# How to implement MVC across the LAN?

Tags: php, delphi, model-view-controller, network-programming, odbc

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so ask how others do this ...

I have 2 upcoming projects, one in Delphi and one in PHP (plus maybe one in Java), so info specific to those would be welcome, but a generic answer is also acceptable.

So, I have a bunch of PCs and a database server (ODBC) and want to develop an MVC app.

I guess that the Model is on the d/b server and that the view is on each individual PC. Where is the controller? One on the d/b server, or one copy on each PC?

When writing data I imagine it is enough to lock the relevant d/b table(?). But how to update all of those views and tell them that there is new data or that the data which they are working on has been modified on deleted by another user?

Any code is welcome as are URLs or book recommendations ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you start with this

```
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
```

Its a regular intranet app right? why do you want to split everything separately. Models, views and controllers are just the respective files where you do the relevant stuff, they dont reside physically on a separate locations. I think you have got the Concept of mvc completely wrong. MVC means splitting and layering the code based on their functions not keeping them physically separate.

To be more clear in a laymans language your models views and controllers are just directories in your application. Your view files goes in to your view directory(not necessarily this is changeable though) your models that is your DB related operation files goes into models and the classes that control and drive your app goes into your controller directory.

Running it on intranet is quiet simple. ALl you have to do is host your files on a system that has a static IP or Name within your network then from other systems go to your browser and point your browser at

http://myserver/myapp or http://192.168.100.100/myapp

I dont know anything about delphi, but what ever i said above stands for PHP and many other languages.

So taking all the above points in you are not going to update the views separately on each system all files are in your central server and any changes made in them automatically reflects when requested from the clients.

From your question i assume you are completely new to web development or atleast mvc so first have a look at some simple mvc like codeigniter in PHP. CI has a very good DOC so you can come up to speed.

Hope i have answered all questions.

Comment: Perhaps he has MVC confused with n-tier? MVC can allow for easier tiering.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I am familiar with MVC on a single PC. Yes, "Its a regular intranet app". But ... "Models, views and controllers ... dont reside physically on a separate locations". Say what now? Fer sure the model resides only on the d/b server. Or?

Comment: I also diagree that "models views and controllers are just directories". Call them units, files, modules, something like that, but directories?

Comment: Ah, I see that when you say "go to your browser" you are thinking of my PHP project. That halpes me understand what you are trying to say. It's probably more the Windwos based .EXE (produced by Delphi) that is giving me problems.

Comment: "you are not going to update the views separately on each system all files are in your central server and any changes made in them automatically reflects when requested from the clients".  Ah, "pull" technology/ I am afraid that I require"push" - which is what MVC is (when done correctly)

Comment: Btw, readig back my comments, they might seem rude - they are certainly not intended to be that way. I think that we are just talking at crossed porpoises. I have awarded you +1 and thank you very much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: no issues at all, thats why i mentioned i m talking abt php as i had no idea abt delphi... glad that you ve got it now :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood MVC, there is no rule about the location of the controller itself.

Please take in consideration that MVC is an [architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29), not an hardware nor even logical design. If, like in any n-Tier architecture, it could make sense to have the DB in a dedicated computer (for performance and maintainability/backup reasons), controllers and views can be... everywhere...

MVC is a *pattern*, that is, more a way of modeling/interfacing objects and classes than a way of distributing your application into modules. In fact, you can (and IMHO should) share MVC code among client and servers, whereas the objects are still implementing Model/View/Controllers in a separated way.

A "classic" MVC implementation (e.g. used by RoR or by [DoR](http://code.google.com/p/delphionrails/) or [Relax](http://code.marcocantu.com/p/delphirelax) in the Delphi world - both in draft status) uses directories or files to split views and controllers. But this is just one implementation design of this pattern.

You can have a [pure object](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/02/Is-Object-Relational-Mapping-the-Paradise-of-Computer-Science) MVC orientation, as we implemented for instance in [our ORM framework](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/08/19/How-to-implement-multi-tier-architecture-in-our-SQLite3-Framework). You can in fact have objects everywhere, to handle your model, to access the DB, to handle your business services.

In our *mORMot Open Source framework*, for Delphi 6-XE, you can follow this development pattern:

- **Data Tier** is either *SQLite3* and/or an internal very fast in-memory database, and/or [any other external database](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/07/SQLite3-powered,-not-SQLite3-limited) (via OleDB or OCI), most SQL queries are created on the fly by the ORM kernel;
- **Logic Tier** is performed by pure ORM aspect: you write Delphi classes which are mapped by the Data Tier into the database, and you can write your business logic in both Client or Server side, just by adding some events or methods to the classes; a [Service-Oriented-Architecture](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/07/18/DataSnap-like-Client-Server-JSON-RESTful-Services-in-Delphi-7-2010) (DataSnap-like) is also available, and can be used without any object;
- **Presentation Tier** is either a Delphi Client, either an AJAX application, or any other back-end able to communicate using RESTful JSON over HTTP/1.1 - in this case, PHP or JAVA clients are perfect candidates.

I suggest you take the time to download and take a look [at the mORMot documentation](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/10/Framework-documentation-updated-to-revision-1.15). It's far from perfect, but it tries to be complete. In the SAD document, you'll find some pages about the architecture we implemented, in particular MVC, n-Tier, SOA and ORM. Don't be afraid of the 1000 pages of PDF - you don't have to read it all: I just added some general diagrams which may help you modeling your solution.

In all cases, taking a breath before implementing a solution for your project is a very good decision. The time you'll spend now by looking at existing architectures will certainly save you pain in the future. Good start!

Comment: +1 MVC is indeed about code organisation. How you split up an MVC app over different physical machines is another matter altogether and you may well end up with the model logic on all physical machines. For example to facilitate client side validation because of its immediacy in addition to server side validation (which requires a round trip).

Comment: @Marjan Your example is exactly what we did for our [RESTful authentication](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/05/24/How-to-implement-RESTful-authentication) mechanism: in fact, the user sessions are stored in memory, for fast access, and to avoid any DB slower round trip. Just an example of MVC approach, which is made even easier because of the ORM (the same objects can be retrieved from the DB, or maintained in memory).